# Are quasicrystals always self-similar?

Tags: fractals, quasicrystals, quasi-periodic

The [diffraction patterns](https://physics.aps.org/story/v28/st14) of quasicrystals very often display self-similarity ie. similarity under length scaling, thus relating them to [fractals](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26918/).

My question is: Do they *always* display self-similarity?

Standard literature (e.g. Janot, 'Quasicrystals: A primer') has not been very helpful since it simply states (without explanation) on p. 34

> It is worth pointing out that quasiperiodic structures are self-similar, but self-similarity generally does not ensure quasiperiodicity, even though it imposes some sort of long-range order.

On the one hand, I wonder how he knows that quasiperiodic structures are self-similar since I think I have a counterexample. The Fibonacci chain (see my related [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/427330/quasiperiodicity-of-the-fibonacci-chain)) with $S = 1$, $L \neq \textrm{golden mean}$, is quasiperiodic but evidently not self-similar.

On the other hand, all the diffraction images of quasicrystals that I have seen *are* self-similar.

So, with my counterexample, am I missing the point? Or is this a dimensionality thing, say in 2D and 3D quasiperiodicity implies self-similarity and in 1D not?

Comment: $\mathbb Z \cup r\mathbb Z$ for $r\in \mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ (or, as a density, $\rho(x) = \sum_n \delta(x-n)+ \sum_n \delta(x-rn)$) is quasiperiodic but not self-similar.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022024804004014 I'm not sure if this is useful to you or not. Perhaps your Fibonacci example is one of non-linear self similarity